# Negative Points and Alternatives to setTag(...)/getTag(...) in Android RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My objective (for the sake of a simple example) is to detect a click on a ImageView inside a LinearLayout. A List of Items, each represented by a LinearLayout, are set using a RecyclerView.

```
public class SomeRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SomeRecyclerAdapter.SomeListViewHolder> {

    ....

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SomeViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    SomeItem item = someList.get(position);

    holder.vImage.setTag(item);
    holder.vImage
            .setOnClickListener(new CompoundButton.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SomeListItem item = (SomeItem) holder.vImage.getTag();
                    Toast.makeText(context, item.getName() + " Image Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    ....

    public static class SomeListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        protected ImageView vImage;

        public SomeListViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            vImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tem_some_list);
        }

    }

}
```

This approach works correctly but, although I don't have enough knowledge to state that, it doesn't seem an efficient implement.

I tried to implement this with onInterceptTouchEvent but I could only get the LinearLayout clicked, meaning the item, and not the button (image, in this case).

Please let me know if I'm write or wrong to assume this and if there is an alternative for what I desire.

Comment: Implement onclick on ImageView instead of linear layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the item to viewholders and have the ViewHolders themselves handle clicks.  Something like this:

```
public class SomeItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
   private final ImageView mImg;
   private SomeItem mBoundItem;

   public SomeItemViewHolder(View view) {
      mImg = view.findViewById(R.id.imageId);
      mImg.setOnClickListener(this);
   }
   ...
   public void bind(SomeItem item) {
      mBoundItem = item;
      // Update the ViewHolder to the item's specifications.
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), mBoundItem.getName() + " Image Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

Then, in the adapter, just call it.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SomeItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
   SomeItem item = someList.get(position);
   holder.bind(item);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you tel me if this solution is better than the one presented by Nikola Despotoski in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703294/how-to-get-specific-view-clicked-from-recyclerview-with-onintercepttouchevent).

Comment: @NBajanca This is a better alternative for "get/setTag" method.  OnInterceptTouchListener is a different issue that I'm not sure what you're trying to do with.  If you just want to make buttons, then you only need OnClickListener.